# exec in php is working inappropriately

Tags: php, linux, command

I am willing to execute a shill command through PHP but i faced that the command is not executing , here is the command:

```
exec('/cutycapt/CutyCapt --url="' . $source . '" --out="/home/user/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/htmlImage/example.png"');
```

i tried as testing to execute the following :

```
echo exec(' ls  /cutycapt/');//print_r is the same
```

only one file returned while this command returned them all

```
echo system(' ls  /cutycapt/');
```

i tried to use the "system" method instead of exec in the first command and the result was the same

what could affect the command so it wan't execute ?

**update**

the case i'm talking bout the the first command work whether i run it in the terminal or i run the PHP script in terminal too but when i run it from the browser (the php script )it doesn't work !!

Comment: Permissions? Do you have enough permissions to execute the command in that folder?

Comment: The `ls` examples are the expected behavior; `exec` returns the last line of output. What makes you think the first command isn't executing? Is there anything in your error logs?

Comment: @Wooble Sir when i run the command in the terminal it takes about 10 sec and it creates a photo  at the path out="/home/user...

Comment: how can i give permissions to php ? should i execute su or sudo and how ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving exec() output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599714/error-retrieving-exec-output)

Answer (score 4):

Look into manual - http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
exec and system returns "The last line from the result of the command"

Answer (score 1):

In case of `system` and `exec` the last line from the result of the command gets returned. 
If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the `passthru()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem working with external commands in php. The problem was related to file permissions. I was using "vchiq" library and the error was "* failed to open vchiq instance". [This page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=56209) might work for you.