# Error retrieving exec() output

Tags: php, linux, curl

I'm using exec to grab curl output (I need to use curl as linux command).

When I start my file using php_cli I see a curl output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 75480  100 75480    0     0  55411      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 60432
```

It means that all the file has been downloaded correctly (~ 75 KB).

I have this code:

```
$page = exec('curl http://www.example.com/test.html');
```

I get a really strange output, I only get: `</html>`

(that's the end of my **test.html** file)

I really do not understand the reason, CURL seems to download all the file, but in $page I only get 7 characters (the lastest 7 characters).

Why?

P.S. I know I can download the source code using other php functions, but I must to use curl (as linux command).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Perl-output to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407590/return-perl-output-to-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless this is a really weird requirement, why not use PHP cURL library instead? You get much finer control on what happens, as well as call parameters (timeout, etc.).

If you really **must** use curl command line binary from PHP:

```
1) Use shell_exec() (this solves your problem)
2) Use 2>&1 at end of command (you might need stderr output as well as stdout)
3) Use the full path to curl utility: do not rely on PATH setting.
```

Comment: There may be times where you need to do something with curl in an environment where PHP doesn't have curl support, so it's still useful to have an external execution fallback.

Answer (score 4):

[RTM for `exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

It returns

> The last line from the result of the command.

You have to set the second parameter to `exec()` that will contain all the output from the command executed.

Example:

```
<?php
$allOutputLines = array();
$returnCode = 0;
$lastOutputLine = exec(
    'curl http://www.example.com/test.html',
    $allOutputLines,
    $returnCode
);

echo 'The command was executed and with return code: ' . $returnCode . "\n";
echo 'The last line outputted by the command was: ' . $lastOutputLine . "\n";
echo 'The full command output was: ' . "\n";
echo implode("\n", $allOutputLines) . "\n";

?>
```